# Can compilers improve performance in real workloads by inserting prefetches in their output?

Tags: compilers, cpu, cpu-cache

Prefetching is a task that the compiler feels like it should be suited for. Prefetching requires knowing in advance what data the program is about to load, and the compiler has a ton of information at its disposal about control flow and what data the program is likely to access in the new future.

And yet, when I could at the output assembly of GCC or LLVM, I never see any prefetches be inserted.

Papers on the subject mention that compiler *could* in theory add prefetches, but never mention whether production compilers *actually* add them in practice. Some compiler have options to add prefetches to the output (`-opt-prefetch[=n]` in ICC, `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` in GCC), but the documentation never mentions whether the pass is even likely to improve performance, let alone for which workloads.

For instance, [the documentation for `-opt-prefetch\[=n\]`](http://www.physics.ntua.gr/%7Ekonstant/HetCluster/intel12.1/compiler_f/main_for/copts/common_options/option_opt_prefetch.htm) says:

> This option enables or disables prefetch insertion optimization. The goal of prefetching is to reduce cache misses by providing hints to the processor about when data should be loaded into the cache.
>
> This option enables prefetching when higher optimization levels are specified.

The documentation says "the goal is", but I've found very little literature on whether it does at all.

And [some reports on manually added software prefetches](https://lwn.net/Articles/444336/) suggest they're rarely worth the space they take:

> CPU designers are well aware of the cost of waiting for memory; they have put a great deal of effort into minimizing that cost whenever possible. Among other things, contemporary CPUs have their own memory prefetch units which attempt to predict which memory will be wanted next and start the process of retrieving it early. One thing Ingo noticed in his tests is that, even without any software prefetch operations, the number of prefetch operations run by the CPU was about the same. So the hardware prefetcher was busy during this time - and it was doing a better job than the software at deciding what to fetch. Throwing explicit prefetch operations into the mix, it seems, just had the effect of interfering with what the hardware was trying to do.

So, my question is: **Do state-of-the-art compilers actually insert prefetches in their output? Is there research showing that doing so actually improves program performance?**

Or do they just interfere with hardware prefetchers for no benefit?

Comment: It seems that you answered yourself your first question (with the compiler options). IMO, the fastest mean to get an answer to the second is to try benchmarking by yourself.

Comment: What is better than prefetching: Massive out-of-order execution. If you can issue a data read 100 instructions or 400 instructions ahead, that is better than any prefetching. And massive caches.